# Class object is not defined

Tags: python

I'm trying to reference class object inside another class. In the sample code below, I want to be able to call Class1 methods from Class3, but they must be created in order where Class1(ClassObject) creates Class2 and Class2 creates Class3. Class3 must be then able to call ClassObject.

Code below gives not defined error.

NameError: global name 'ClassObject' is not defined

Any workarounds or fixes to this problem?

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        Class2()

    def method(self):
        print("test")

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        Class3()

class Class3:
    def __init__(self):
         ClassObject.method()


ClassObject = Class1()
```

Comment: Either assign your instances to member variables or use inheritance. (Depending on what exactly you want). Please explain what you want to archive in more detail.

Comment: This makes no sense. You seem to assume some inheritance, but there is no inheritance. Please explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: your code is a total non-sense and shows that you really lack basic understanding of python code. Please read at least an introduction course to object oriented programming, and to python…

Answer (score 3):

Assignment are executed right to the left. It means that `Class1()` is computed before ClassObject is defined. 
Before the affectation, the global scope looks like `['Class1', 'Class2', 'Class3']`.

So the following stack happens:

```
"Class1()" is called -> get Class1 reference in the global scope
Class1.__init__
   -> "Class2()" is called -> get Class2 reference in the global scope
   -> Class2.__init__
       -> "Class3()" is called -> ... you might know now.
       -> Class3.__init__
          -> ClassObject.method()
          -> try to get ClassObject from global scope
          -> raises exception: ClassObject isn't defined
```

Inde

I would like to give you a valid code, but your 3 classes haven't any meanings...

Comment: well, your explanation is quite accurate, but I think that you need to tell a lot more for the OP to understand what's happening. I'm +1 for trying ;-)

Comment: @Bakuriu Not very the same answer, but I agree, I don't understand your downvote too.

Comment: May I ask you why do you use the term *affectation*? I'm not English mothertongue but it just seems wrong. Do you mean assignement? Expression? Or what?

Comment: @Bakuriu Because I was probably thinking about the French word "Affectation" (which means assignment) when I was writing and so... get mixed in my head :)

Comment: The code sample was simplified and pretty mindless. The problem I'm having relates to Tkinter, where I have multiple windows and each window has its own class. So a button in window 1 opens window 2. Window 2 then tries to interract with the window 1 the similar way class3 tries to interract with class1 in the sample code, calling a method. And regarding to your explanation, would the ClassObject = Class1() defining happen after the exception?

Comment: You can't (and you shouldn't have to) use the global variable `ClassObject` in your `__init__` methods. That's all.

Comment: What about using it in other methods than __init__? I'm not actually using it in that. I'm sorry about the stupid example.

Answer (score 0):

When `Class1()` is called there is no `ClassObject` global variable.

Since in python there are no variable declarations, the variable can be accessed only when it is *defined*, which means when it has a value. In your case the value would the that instance, but that instance is trying to reference the global variable *before* the assignment is complete.

If you want to reference the object in the assignment you *must* use `self`. However, in your code `Class3` doesn't have any access to the `Class1` instance so you'll get a different error.

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain? The error **is** due to the global not being defined at that time.

Comment: Didn’t downvote but `Class3` doesn’t have a `method` method.

Comment: @poke So? `Class3` references `ClassObject` which is a `Class1` instance which **does** have `method`. the problem is what I stated.

Comment: You said to use `self` though, and `self.method()` won’t work inside `Class3`…

Comment: @poke I first stated that because I thought they were subclasses, and forgot to change it when edited. I'm changing that line now. However my point is valid. Before the first assignment of an instance the only way to access it in `__init__` is to use `self`.